# Running ansible on ec2 instance from gitlab runner without SSH key?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, apache-kafka, ansible, terraform

I have a git lab runner whose job it is to:

a) Create IaC using Terraform. (7 ec2 instances with a defined keypair)
b) Run an ansible playbook that will need to SSH to all 7 instances and configure Kafka.

At the moment, I have automated part a. I then ssh to one of the instances using a private key. copy the ansible code and the private key to the instance and then execute the following cmd to run the ansible:

```
ansible-playbook --private-key=/home/ec2-user/keyname.pem hosts.yml all.yml
```

This all works fine but obviously, I want to automate the running of the ansible in a gitlab runner without having to store my private key on the docker container or in the git repo.

I have briefly investigated SSM but don't really understand how that all works.
Note: I need the key for two purposes.

1. ssh into the first instance
2. referenced in the host.yml so that the ansible playbook can connect to all other instances

Thanks in advance everyone.
Cheers
Adam

Comment: The [GitLab CI variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/README.html#custom-environment-variables-of-type-file) supports a file type, which  can be set at the project or group level, and will be injected into the Job but then will evaporate when the Job ends; have you tried that?

Comment: How does the ssh key get added as a variable?

Comment: That sounds like a new question, separate from your current one; thankfully, [this site has a search function](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgitlab%5D+ssh+private+key+ci+variable)